# How can I use the navigation options on this screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have two files named App.js and ActivityScreen.js. I want to make the navigationOptions settings of the Activity file over the ActivityScreen.js file, not App.js.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    ...
}
```

feature doesn't work, please don't offer it.

*App.js*

```
<Stack.Screen name="Activity" component={ActivityScreen} options={({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Aktiviteler',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#EE7301' },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('AddActivity') } style={{ marginRight: 12 }}>
        <Icon
          style={styles.icon}
          fill='#FFFFFF'
          name='plus-outline'
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
)})} />
```

Comment: Do you mean setting from ActivityScreen? If so, try prop.navigation.setOption method

Comment: @SaachiTech That's it! Thanks dude.